# Yoneda Lemma question

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Be $\mathcal{C}$ a category, $M \in \mathcal{C}$ and $F$ a funtor of $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{C}_{Set}$.
By Yoneda Lemma we have that Hom(Hom($M$,-),$F$)$=F(M)$. I understand in the proof that we have a biyection from Hom(Hom(M,-),F) to $F$ but I don`t understand the "$=$".

And I don´t understand that $M \simeq M' \Leftrightarrow \text{Hom(}M\text{,-)} \simeq \text{Hom(}M'\text{,-)}$.

Comment: The equal sign should be a natural isomorphism.

Comment: Yes but ¿betwenn functors?

Comment: Actually, what the Yoneda Lemma says is that there is a bijection between the sets $Hom(Hom(M,-))\cong F(M)$ if $F$ is a functor from $C$ to **Set**.

Comment: And $F$ is a funtor from C to Set.

Comment: @topologicalspace1234 Is your most recent comment supposed to be a question?

Comment: I don't understand you.

Answer (score 2):

The Yoneda Lemma says that there is a bijection $Hom(Hom(M,-),F)\cong F(M)$. The equal sign, if you have encountered the lemma written with it instead of the isomorphism sign, is an abuse of notation. It is very common to regard isomorphic objects as being the same. For instance, the groups $\{-1,1\}$ with the product and $\{0,1\}$ with the sum modulo $2$ are both isomorphic to the cyclic group of order two. They are not literally the same, but we can say that both groups are the cyclic group of order $2$. And the same happens a lot with any other equivalence relation (the actual realization of this idea is the quotient). Morever, the isomorphism (bijection in this case) is natural on both $M$ and $F$, so we can treat them as equal in many categorical circumstances.

Natural in $M$ means that a morphism $M\to M'$ induces a morphism $Hom(Hom(M,-),F)\to Hom(Hom(M',-),F)$, which is an isomorphism if $M\to M'$ is an isomorphism. Similarly the naturality in $F$.

As per the other question, there is a nice answer [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2127355/natural-isomorphism-of-hom-functors-imply-isomorphism-of-objects). I think the non accepted answer might be more enlightening if you have problems understanding the Yoneda embedding.

Comment: You say that the isomorphism is natural on both $M$ and $F$. But a natural isomorphism is defined between two functors, ¿what 2 functors in this case?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine sorry, a typo, thanks

Comment: @topologicalspace1234 Natural in $M$ implies that the functor $M\mapsto Hom(Hom(M,-),F)$ is naturally isomorphich to the fuctor $F$. Natural in $F$ implies that the functor $F\mapsto Hom(Hom(M,-),F)$ is naturally isomorphic to the functor $F\mapsto F(M)$. I think this is better understood in terms of induced isomorphisms, which is what I'm going to write on the answer.